# Are these walls around the closet load-bearing?

Tags: walls, closet

we just recently purchased a house and wanted to see if I can knock out the walls around the closet to put in built-in shelving. Do you think these are load bearing? [image: K]

Comment: Is there a notation anywhere on that drawing for what 'E' in a diamond box means?

Comment: Yep. It's toward the lower left, and indicates shear walls. Those are almost certainly the bearing walls. We don't have enough information to be sure, though, as with nearly all of these questions.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think those are bearing walls. The nearby shear walls are more likely to be such, but modern roof systems don't usually bear on interior walls like those anyway.

Do I *know* they're not load bearing? Nope. Look in your attic. If you're taking them out you'll be in there anyway.